# Double Dereference in struct C

Tags: c, struct, dereference

I have the following code. It seems the reading sequence is wrong. Any help?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct punct{
int x;
int y;
}COORD;

typedef struct nod{
COORD *coord;
struct nod *urm;
}NOD;
int main()
{
  NOD *head= malloc( sizeof(NOD) );
  scanf("%d", &head->coord->x );
  scanf("%d", &head->coord->y );
  printf("%d, %d", head->coord->x , head->coord->y);

  return 0;
}
```

I have successfully managed to access only the x field of the struct by using `head->coord`, and from what I can tell that's the issue with my code. I'm already on the first field of the first struct so I can't access x/y because of that.

Comment: Where do you initialise `head->coord`?

Comment: Try with some proper paranthesis: `scanf("%d", &((head->coord)->y));`

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Thanks, didn't think about that. Thought I got it covered with the initialisation of head.

Comment: @nica.dan.cs Already did that, and it was of no use.

Comment: @nica.dan.cs: what on  earth are the parentheses for — apart from confusing a poor newcomer and trying to instill bad practices in them.  Those parentheses are pointless!  Do *not* use parentheses in that expression.

Comment: @nica.dan.cs:  Those parentheses do not change the order of evaluation:  it adds extra text with no difference in effect.  You might want to review the [expression evaluation order](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: I did not know those paranthesis don't change anything. As, far as I remember, they told us to do this in college, as some sort of good practice thing. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: in C, the memory allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc) can fail.  TO avoid an unexpected seg fault event, alway check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful, before using that returned value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't initialized `head->coord`. Dereferencing uninitialized pointers result in [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You need to do something like:

```
  head->coord = malloc( sizeof (COORD) );
```

You should also check the return value of `malloc()` for failures.

Answer (score 4):

You did not initialize the coord variable so you shoud malloc some space for that too.

`head->coord = malloc( sizeof (COORD) );`

But in this case it might be best to put COORD in NOD instead of referencing to it!

So:

```
typedef struct nod{
   COORD coord;
   struct nod *urm;
}NOD;
```

You should only really make a pointer to it when you are going to swap the object a lot or when its a more complex object.

Comment: Embedding the `COORD` directly seems correct here.  If it was to be an array of `COORD` values, then you'd need a count too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Say I want to create an array of COORD. How do I create a link between  lets say an array `COORD  **A = malloc( n * sizeof( COORD* ) );` , where n is the number of x,y pairs, and a list of type NOD elements. I was thinking about a for until head is NULL, where head is the beginning of my list, where with each iteration I do `A[i]->x= head->coord->x` and `A[i]->y= head->coord->y`. Any thoughts?

Comment: @AlexPostolache: assuming a structure like: `typedef struct nod { size_t num_coords; COORD *coord; struct nod *urm; } NOD;`, then you'd define `NOD *nod = malloc(sizeof(*nod)); if (nod == 0) { …error…; } nod->coord = malloc(n * sizeof(*nod->coord)); if (nod->coord == 0) { …error…; free(nod); } nod->num_coords = n; nod->urm = 0;` or thereabouts.  That allocates the array of coordinates for use by the structure: `nod->coord[0]` .. `nod->coord[nod->num_coords - 1]` are valid references.